# How do I compress only the top part of an image in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

On inkscape, I am trying to make an SVG of a map that I drew, and I am trying to line it up with another map that I traced off of it. I imported pictures of both maps and tried to align them, however, the pictures were taken at a slightly different angle with my phone. When I stretched them out, rotated them, and aligned them, one was bigger on the top than the other one. Is there a way that I could compress the top part of the image, or a way to get around this problem?

Comment: inkscape is for vector graphics. you might be better of with gimp if you're editing photos.
post your pictures to make clear what you want to achieve. why can't you just select the upper region an edit that?

Comment: On [this example](http://imgur.com/L1N33Of), I am trying to line up the picture, but I need the left side to be compressed to properly line up the pictures.